# SUM of all, but COUNT of unique, in one query

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I have two queries

```
   SELECT SUM(amount) as amount FROM sales
   SELECT COUNT(id) as total FROM sales GROUP BY rep_id
```

How can I combine these two queries into one?
If I group by on the first it adds up only the grouped by amounts.

Comment: Can you provide your desired output? ie one row with sum and unique count and nothing else, or one row per rep with sum and count for that rep?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

SELECT SUM(amount) as amount,(SELECT COUNT(id) as total FROM sales GROUP BY rep_id) FROM sales

Answer (score 0):

```
 Select (Select Sum(Amount) from sales) Amount,
     count(*) total  
 from sales 
 group by repID
```

But understand, this will produce one row per RepID, with the total sales amount for all repIds, and the count of sales for only that repId, on every row.

T\Presenting data this way where one column of data on every row contains data for only that row, and another column contains a value that sums all the rows, is potentially very confusing and misleading.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by using `UNION` keyword. According with MySql documentation,

> > *`UNION` is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT statements into a single result set*.

In practice, according with your both SQL Queries:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as total FROM sales
UNION
SELECT COUNT(id) as total FROM sales 
GROUP BY rep_id
```

Notice that the above query generates one single column with the same alias. But that's not a poblem because you already knows which row matches which query.